# Subtract 2 identical images (B&W and colorful) to get color difference

Tags: python, ruby, image-processing, vips

I have mostly black and white image, with some parts in color (let's say it's yellow and green). **I would like to find out those colors.**

For that, I suppose I might convert image to black & white, and then compare b & w image with original one to find the difference. But I'm not quite sure which algorithm I should use to do that.

Something like that in pseudocode:

```
image = image_from_file('image.jpg')
bw_image = image.convert_to_bw
diff_image = (bw_image - image)
# Build histogram w/o black and white parts, only color ones
diff_image.histogram
```

I'm primary focused on libvips to do that, but I just need an advice of how to do that in general, then I'll be able to code that.

I would also appreciate if you know any other way to do what I described above.

Comment: By black and white do you mean grayscale or binary black and white?

Comment: Would this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16721373/9356981

Comment: @Jello greyscale

Comment: @AdamMoller thanks, that might help, I'll try to rewrite it using ruby

Comment: Can you provide a sample image please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby-vips you could do:

```
require 'vips'

a = Vips::Image.new_from_file ARGV[0]

# convert to LCh colourspace
a = a.colourspace "lch"

# Chroma (band 1) > 0 means we have some colour ... take > 10, since things 
# like jpg compression will add some colour noise we are not 
# interested in
mask = a[1] > 10

# the mask image will have 255 for TRUE pixels and 0 for FALSE
mask.write_to_file "mask.png"
```

The mask image might not be very helpful, but I'm not clear exactly what output you need.

[LCh colourspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space#Cylindrical_representation:_CIELCh_or_CIEHLC) is useful here: band 1 (ie. C) is the distance of the pixel from the neutral axis, exactly what you want, I think.

Answer (score 3):

The right approach here is to convert to HSV or a similar color space that separates out saturation or chroma. Then find pixels with a high value for saturation/chroma.

The hue component of the HSV (or similar) color space then gives you the color for those pixels (yellow or green, as an angle on the chromaticity plane).

I cannot post code because you have tagged the question with two different languages, and I have no idea which of them is the code snippet you posted. I hope you can take it from here.